# How to get Area or specific location boundaries using flutter map? (With Flutter Map only , not in GOOGLE MAPS)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I need to show area boundaries in my flutter map like in Google Maps. If I click or search any area or city I need to show the boundaries of that area or city how to do it. I attached a sample image for reference.[Area image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3mSe.jpg)

I have searched my sites none of the results are not satisfied with my output. Where to get the area service boundaries.